# How to get result of async call in parent function scope

Tags: typescript, scope

I am new to angular and using `angular 2 with typescript` and having an issue with putting the values into the variables.

Also i have seen typescript documentation about `let` and it's **block scoping**:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html

But the issue might be due to the `third log` getting called before `second log`, which is an ajax request calling the server.

This is my code where i am using `let`:

```
getData() {
    let value : any;
    console.log('first console log:'+value);
    this.http
        .get('api/get')
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(response => {
            value = response;
            console.log('second console log:'+value);
        });
    console.log('third console log:'+value);
}
```

And the output is:

```
first console log:undefined
third console log:undefined
second console log:[object Object]
```

**How do i get the value of response into the variable?**

Comment: what is happening here is thirst it is printing first console and than directly printing third console and in last its printing second log. i have faced same issue. i think code running async that is why happening. if you found any solution please update here.

Comment: @VinayPandya what solution? There isn't any problem/question.

Comment: @echonax may be we can use promise but havn't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is asynchronous. So the `.subscribe()` will arrive when the ajax call is resolved. Your third console.log is in the main application flow and will get executed directly after the ajax call is fired on a different thread. Thus your value is not initiated yet.

If you would have written this code using callbacks it might be more clear what happens:

```
getData() {
  let value : any;
  this.http.get('api/get', (res, err) => {
    value = res;
    console.log('second console log:' + value);
  });
  console.log('third console log:' + value);
}
```

A solution without Rx would be to use promises

```
getData() {
  let value : any;
  this.http.get('api/get')
    .then(res => {
      value = res;
      console.log('second console log:' + value);
    });
  console.log('third console log:' + value);
}
```

But you have to realise it is just lingo to hide the callback and give you chainable `.then()` syntax.

The true problem is that the third console line is on the main thread (when you enter the `getData()` function) and the asynchronous code will be scheduled on a different thread to run at its own pace. So the third console log will never align with that code.

The fix is to add the third console log line to the `.subscribe()`, the `.then()` or the callback whatever path you choose.

Comment: so what is the solution @mark. can we use promise for that?

Comment: I don't think editing the question the way you did is appropriate. The question is really vague and I admit the way you've changed it makes sense but OP has already said: "issue might be due to the third log getting called before second log, which is an ajax request calling the server." so this indicates OP knows about the async nature. And why did you remove the `angular2`, `rxjs` and `observable` tags? This is an `angular2` code using an `observable` from the `rxjs` library.

Comment: As the author has already stated his question is about scoping of his variables and has nothing to do with angular/observable/rxjs specific code. The title of the question was vague and did not hint anything at the question at hand.